# add custom field in checkout page magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, checkout-page, custom-field

i want to add a custom field in checkout page in magento 1.9 . The custom field should ask where do you hear about us? and should have options as radio button such as fb,google,friend etc. i want to edit using code any help would be
appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many free and paid modules available for the same purpose in Magento 1.x.

You can take help from any free module and customize it according to your requirement.

Below are some reference links:

http://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/Inchoo_Heared4us.zip

Tutorial link: http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-a-new-tab-under-one-page-checkout-full-working-module/

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: yeah, inchoo one will work